# Working with authorized .net payment gateway in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am working with authorized .net payement gateway in ios
In the following method

```
 (void) createTransaction {
    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

    [an setDelegate:self];

    CreditCardType *creditCardType = [CreditCardType creditCardType];
    creditCardType.cardNumber = @"4111111111111111";
    NSLog(@"babul cardNumber is %@",creditCardType.cardNumber);
    creditCardType.cardCode = @"100";
    NSLog(@"babul cardCode is %@",creditCardType.cardCode);
    creditCardType.expirationDate = @"1212";
    NSLog(@"babul expirationDate is %@",creditCardType.expirationDate);
    PaymentType *paymentType = [PaymentType paymentType];
    paymentType.creditCard = creditCardType;

    ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeTax = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
    extendedAmountTypeTax.amount = @"0";
    extendedAmountTypeTax.name = @"Tax";

    ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeShipping = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
    extendedAmountTypeShipping.amount = @"0";
    extendedAmountTypeShipping.name = @"Shipping";

    LineItemType *lineItem = [LineItemType lineItem];
    lineItem.itemName = @"Soda";
    lineItem.itemDescription = @"Soda";
    lineItem.itemQuantity = @"1";
    lineItem.itemPrice = @"1.00";
    lineItem.itemID = @"1";

    TransactionRequestType *requestType = [TransactionRequestType transactionRequest];
    requestType.lineItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lineItem];
    requestType.amount = @"1.00";
    requestType.payment = paymentType;
    requestType.tax = extendedAmountTypeTax;  
    requestType.shipping = extendedAmountTypeShipping;

   CreateTransactionRequest *request = [CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest];
    request.transactionRequest = requestType;
    request.transactionType = AUTH_ONLY;
    request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
    request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.sessionToken = sessionToken;
    [an purchaseWithRequest:request];
}
```

i am getting the response as

Create Transaction response
2012-07-26 19:14:00.131 Authorized[2355:207] Error`E00003`The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'mobileDeviceId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"
                                                                               ^
2012-07-26 19:14:00.131 Authorized[2355:207] Error = (null)
2012-07-26 19:14:00.247 Authorized[2355:207] babul output is Message.code = E00003
Message.text = The element 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'mobileDeviceId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'name, transactionKey, sessionToken, password' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

Is there any alternative to the above problem and how the transactions are going to be stored in authorized .net
(i created my test account, i am giving those credentials, i approved my device but later i am getting the above error)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go for in app purchase because Apple will not approve application payment through any web service or API.

Comment: Not correct. This applies only for virtual goods like e.g. Software or Services. If you sell physical goods like e.g. a car, you will have to use your own / third party payment solutions.